# android sockets work on emulator but not on my real device

Tags: java, android, sockets

Here is part of my source code, it works perfectly on the emulator but not on the real phone. there are some answers that said it is about the server's firewall setting. May I ask how to set a proper firewall that would allow android data passing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.Provider;

public class LocationService extends Service {

    public class sendLocation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

//        public static final String SERVER_IP_ADDRESS = "10.50.xx.xx";
        public static final String SERVER_IP_ADDRESS = "10.152.xx.xx";
        public static final int PORT = 8000;
        /**
         * send the data to the server
         * @param strings
         * @return
         */

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String location_info = strings[0];
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS,PORT);
//                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Connected to the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                pw.write(location_info);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null){
                double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
//                Log.d("LOCATION_UPDATE",latitude + " , " + longitude);
                String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Device ID:" + androidId + " \nLOCATION_UPDATE" + latitude + " , " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new sendLocation().execute("Device ID:" + androidId + " ; Latitude:" + latitude + " ; Longitude:" + longitude);
            }

        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        throw  new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implement yet!");
    }

    private void startLocationService(){
        String channelId = "location_notification_channel";
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext(),
                channelId
        );
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Location Service");
        builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
        builder.setContentText("Running");
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            if (notificationManager != null
                    && notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId) == null){
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        channelId,
                        "Location Service",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                );
                notificationChannel.setDescription("This channel is used by location service");
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }

        }

        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(4000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
        startForeground(Constants.LOCATION_SERVICE_ID,builder.build());
    }

    private void stopLocationService(){
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                .removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        if (intent != null){
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action != null){
                if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_START_LOCATION_SERVICE)){
                    startLocationService();
                } else if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_STOP_LOCATION_SERVICE)){
                    stopLocationService();
                }
            }
        }
        return  super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }
}
```